# TypeScript failing on React typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack

I'm sure there's something stupid that I'm missing, but I can't get my TypeScript compiler to compile a fairly simply React component. I'm using a `.tsx` file extension for my file which TypeScript should be able to handle via my webpack config. I get the following error: `ERROR in ./src/App.tsx
(36,16): error TS2339: Property 'todos' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ToDosList> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> &...'.`

Below is my code. I've tried both implicitly setting the state for the component (meaning without setting state: App.State) and explicitly giving `state` a type of `App.State`, but neither seem to work.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ToDosList from './components/todos_list';

const todos = [
    {
        task: 'Make React tutorial',
        is_completed: false
    },
    {
        task: 'Eat Dinner',
        is_completed: true
    }
];

namespace App {
    export interface Props {

    }

    export interface State {
        todos: any
    }
}

export default class App extends React.Component<App.Props, App.State> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { todos: todos };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React ToDos App</h1>
                <ToDosList todos={this.state.todos} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I thought it was yelling because it couldn't read this.state.todos here, but it was actually yelling because the ToDosList component didn't type the props having a `todos` attribute.